# Why the result of the RSA encryption in C# is different from JavaScript？

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core

I want to run my C# code to login a web site, so I need to implement the RSA Encryption method in the web site. Below is my C# and JavaScript test code to encrypt "test", but they display the different results.How to modify the C# code to get the same result as the JavaScript code？

JavaScript：Save the code to a html file and opened by web browser will see the result.

Or run the code online:https://onlinegdb.com/fzKiCrbGf

It is the JavaScript RSA library with documentation comments:http://www.ohdave.com/rsa/RSA.js

```
<script src="http://www.ohdave.com/rsa/RSA.js"></script>
<script src="http://www.ohdave.com/rsa/Barrett.js"></script>
<script src="http://www.ohdave.com/rsa/BigInt.js"></script>
<script>
setMaxDigits(130);
var key = new RSAKeyPair("010001","","906C793510FB049452764740B21B97A51DAEA794AB6E43836269D5E6317D49226C12362BA22DAB5EC3BC79553A8A098B01F3C4D81A87B3EE5BD2F4F1431CC495EE2FE54688B212145BB32D56EEEEE1430CE26234331B291CFC53C9B84FAFFDF0B44371A032880C3D567F588D2CD5FCE28D9CDD2923CB547DAD219A6A1B8B5D3D");
var result=encryptedString(key,"test")
document.write(result);
</script>
```

C#：It is the code of the C# Consloe Program.Run the code will see the result output to the consloe.

Or run the code online:https://onlinegdb.com/B1wG_5rXu

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        System.Security.Cryptography.RSAParameters rsaParams = new System.Security.Cryptography.RSAParameters
        {
            Modulus = HexToByteArray("906C793510FB049452764740B21B97A51DAEA794AB6E43836269D5E6317D49226C12362BA22DAB5EC3BC79553A8A098B01F3C4D81A87B3EE5BD2F4F1431CC495EE2FE54688B212145BB32D56EEEEE1430CE26234331B291CFC53C9B84FAFFDF0B44371A032880C3D567F588D2CD5FCE28D9CDD2923CB547DAD219A6A1B8B5D3D"),
            Exponent = HexToByteArray("010001"),
        };
        System.Security.Cryptography.RSACryptoServiceProvider rsa = new System.Security.Cryptography.RSACryptoServiceProvider();
        rsa.ImportParameters(rsaParams);
        byte[] result = rsa.Encrypt(System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("test"), false);
        System.Console.Write(ByteArrayToHex(result));
        System.Console.ReadKey();
    }

    public static byte[] HexToByteArray(string hex)
    {
        return Enumerable.Range(0, hex.Length)
                         .Where(x => x % 2 == 0)
                         .Select(x => Convert.ToByte(hex.Substring(x, 2), 16))
                         .ToArray();
    }

    public static string ByteArrayToHex(byte[] ba)
    {
        System.Text.StringBuilder hex = new System.Text.StringBuilder(ba.Length * 2);
        foreach (byte b in ba)
            hex.AppendFormat("{0:x2}", b);
        return hex.ToString();
    }
}
```

Comment: The .NET version won't even be consistent with itself from run to run.  You're using PKCS#1 v1.5 padding, which adds random data to the plaintext before encrypting.

Comment: if add random data to the plaintext , the results should be different for each running. But they are the same.

Comment: If I click on the link you provided to run the C# code, and press run, I get one value, then if I press run, I get another value.  It's different on each run.

Comment: Sorry , I was wrong, It's different on each run. Is it possible to remove the padding before encrypting？

Comment: No.  C#'s implementation only supports [two padding options](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography.rsacryptoserviceprovider.encrypt?view=net-5.0#System_Security_Cryptography_RSACryptoServiceProvider_Encrypt_System_Byte___System_Security_Cryptography_RSAEncryptionPadding_), both of which use random bytes.

Comment: @深秋的黎明 you already asked this question once. The answer is the same - the Javascript library is wrong. End of story. Use one of the *common, maintained* RSA encyption libraries instead.

Comment: @AnonCoward the OP already posted an identical question yesterday and didn't like the answer that the JavaScript library is faulty. No explanation was given why they don't use a common JavaScript encryption library

Comment: @深秋的黎明 I told you yesterday that this custom, weak encryption is worse than HTTPS. You can consider it broken by default as well, as hackers created scripts to break textbook implementation years, if not decades ago. Worst case, since this encryption is deterministic, one only needs to compare the "encrypted" text to precalculated encrypted passwords to find a match in less than 1 second

Comment: @深秋的黎明 a simple [search for RSA at npm](https://www.npmjs.com/search?q=rsa&ranking=popularity) returns libraries with millions of downloads, like `node-forge`, `browserify-rsa`, `node-rsa`. Is there *any* good reason you want to use that script, and be liable for any security breaches since you knowingly used weak encryption?

Answer (score 2):

The JavaScript library uses [textbook rsa](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/1448) by default, i.e. none of the usual (non-deterministic) paddings ([PKCS#1 v1.5](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc8017#section-7.2) or [OAEP](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc8017#section-7.1)) are applied (note that the JavaScript library also supports PKCS#1 v1.5 padding).
[textbook RSA is insecure](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/20085) and should therefore not be used in practice! As noted in the comment, .NET does not support this insecure variant out-of-the-box, so a third-party library must be applied, e.g. [BouncyCastle](https://www.bouncycastle.org/csharp/index.html).

Furthermore, the JavaScript library internally **reverses** the order of the plaintext, which must therefore be done explicitly in the C# code.

The JavaScript code below:

```js
setMaxDigits(130);
var key = new RSAKeyPair("010001","","906C793510FB049452764740B21B97A51DAEA794AB6E43836269D5E6317D49226C12362BA22DAB5EC3BC79553A8A098B01F3C4D81A87B3EE5BD2F4F1431CC495EE2FE54688B212145BB32D56EEEEE1430CE26234331B291CFC53C9B84FAFFDF0B44371A032880C3D567F588D2CD5FCE28D9CDD2923CB547DAD219A6A1B8B5D3D");
var result=encryptedString(key,"test")
document.write(result);
```

```html
<script src="http://www.ohdave.com/rsa/BigInt.js"></script>
<script src="http://www.ohdave.com/rsa/Barrett.js"></script>
<script src="http://www.ohdave.com/rsa/RSA.js"></script>
```

produces the following ciphertext:

```
4331ef280f5fd4f4c53fc2367c90fceb5cc65eca7b343cb5e67c120e4a47202e5343f9b9952f885542053d7c408495a2a3f53da9d13839fcd5b0fc044543ffccd44e8057015534c4ff0f1b849619cf0e5b2c86751c6f6effbc4555158c5000876cc0bb5915abdfbcf211be8a195a97b3fb1662c71a20d8183c589da5a5549b55
```

A possible implementation in C# that provides the result of the JavaScript code is:

```cs
using Org.BouncyCastle.Crypto.Parameters;
using Org.BouncyCastle.Math;
using Org.BouncyCastle.Security;
using System;
using System.Text;

...

// Encode plaintext and reverse order
string plaintext = "test";
var dataToEncrypt = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(plaintext);
Array.Reverse(dataToEncrypt);

// Import key via modulus and public exponent
string modulus = "906C793510FB049452764740B21B97A51DAEA794AB6E43836269D5E6317D49226C12362BA22DAB5EC3BC79553A8A098B01F3C4D81A87B3EE5BD2F4F1431CC495EE2FE54688B212145BB32D56EEEEE1430CE26234331B291CFC53C9B84FAFFDF0B44371A032880C3D567F588D2CD5FCE28D9CDD2923CB547DAD219A6A1B8B5D3D";
string exponent = "010001";
BigInteger rsaPubMod = new BigInteger(modulus, 16);
BigInteger rsaPubExp = new BigInteger(exponent, 16);
RsaKeyParameters rsaPublic = new RsaKeyParameters(false, rsaPubMod, rsaPubExp);

// Encrypt with NoPadding (= textbook RSA) - Be aware that this is insecure!!!
var cipher = CipherUtilities.GetCipher("RSA/NONE/NoPadding");
cipher.Init(true, rsaPublic);
var encryptedData = cipher.DoFinal(dataToEncrypt);

// Hex encode the data
var encryptedDataHex = BitConverter.ToString(encryptedData).Replace("-", "").ToLower();

Console.WriteLine(encryptedDataHex); // 4331ef280f5fd4f4c53fc2367c90fceb5cc65eca7b343cb5e67c120e4a47202e5343f9b9952f885542053d7c408495a2a3f53da9d13839fcd5b0fc044543ffccd44e8057015534c4ff0f1b849619cf0e5b2c86751c6f6effbc4555158c5000876cc0bb5915abdfbcf211be8a195a97b3fb1662c71a20d8183c589da5a5549b55
```

Comment: Deterministic means a rainbow table can be used to find the password if a hacker is too lazy to use one of the cracking tools targeting textbook implementations. One has to wonder whether that's the whole point - the OP asked an identical question yesterday and didn't like the answer that the script is at fault, or that a popular library should be used instead

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos - Yes, I agree. Deleting an old question and posting more or less the same question is a bad habit, since all the information about the previous question is lost and has to be worked out again with a corresponding time investment. It's also kind of disrespectful to those who took the time to help with the deleted question.